# Too many ender dragons

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

My friend and I are playing Tekkit. Since we've got all that fancy stuff, we decided to go to the end. We spawned there one a lonely platform and flew over to the island, and we saw about 50 enderdragons.
We have good weapons, but it would take hours to kill them all! Why are there so many? And how do we escape the end, without killing ourselves?

Comment: Are you the only players, or are there others? If there are others, are any of them ops? (Ops can spawn Enderdragons.)

Comment: No. Only my friend and i are playing on the server.

Comment: It'd be really cool if you could post a screencap -- that sounds pretty intense. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To escape the End, use a data editor to change your dimension and location back to the Overworld spawn point. [NTBExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/840677-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac/) is excellent for this.

Normally I would consider edits like that cheats, but when the world is clearly bugged its a sensible option.